# Connect to an offline Wi-Fi and keep using mobile data (for all other apps, too)

Tags: android, android-wifi

I have an app that needs to connect to a hardware via Wi-Fi. For this purpose, the hardware offers an **offline Wi-Fi Hotspot**. The hotspot's DHCP doesn't give us a gateway or DNS so we know right away, that it's for offline use only.

The end user will be at work and have to stay connected to the Wi-Fi the whole time in order to receive sensor data and alerts if something is wrong with the data. But at the same time, we don't want to force the end user to be offline with his mobile device. He should be able to use his mobile data for our and all other apps he has.

I though I can control this by calling [android.net.ConnectivityManager.requestNetwork](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager#requestNetwork(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)). But it doesn't seem to work reliably. Will calling `requestNetwork` in **my app** influence if **all the other apps** have access to mobile data?

Is this even something that we can control? I tested this on multiple devices with different manufacturers and android versions and they all behave differently.

E.g. Pixel 3a works fine. After some time I get a notification regarding the offline Wi-Fi. If I ignore it, it keeps working. If I press "yes" on it, I am offline and connected to the Wi-Fi.

Huawei P20 Lite seems to fire a `OnLost` event for my mobile data `NetworkCallback` every time I request it. Like its trying to cancel the mobile connection every time I reconnect because I'm in the wifi. Some devices offer a "Smart Switch" (Samsung) or "Wi-Fi+" (Huawei) mode which isn't on per default. And it seems like a hassle to ask the user to turn it on, since they might not want to use it in different scenarios.

Here are some examples for the different devices:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying this out on various devices, I can say, that it is not possible to achive the desired behaviour consinstently on all devices.
Pretty much all the devices, behave differently. The OS-version is not really a factor. It depends more on how the vendors handle the case, that a user is connected to an offline wifi.

Based on the device, it might be possible to stay connected to offline wifi and use mobile data at the same time for all apps. But the OS can automatically disconnect you or lock you into the offline-wifi and disable mobile data. Maybe it does it because the user selected an option in the system dialogs as shown above.

In the latter case, it is possible to force a mobile data connection with the `ConnectivityManager` for the **own app**. But it is not possible to make all the other apps use this mobile connection as well.

Answer (score 1):

When using `requestNetwork()` to stick to an offline wifi network, you need an instance of `ConnectivityManager`. You can get it as follows:

```
final ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

This method returns the OS's connectivity manager. Therefore other apps will also be impacted by the "sticky" mode you've put the `ConnectivityManager` in.

Unfortunately I don't think it's possible for an app to force OS to stay connected to an offline Wifi network, and at the same time keep using mobile data.

Comment: I've just tested it with an example app. I get the ConnectivityManager, call `requestNetwork` with a network that has the `NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET` and `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR` capabilities.
However, I am still offline after this. If I call `ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(network)` in this NetworkCallback only my app is online. The rest of the os is still stuck with the offline WiFi.

Comment: Have you tried calling ConnectivityManager.bindProcessToNetwork(null); to reset the "sticky" Wifi preference ?

Comment: Yes, indeed. No matter what I do in may app, with `bindProcessToNetwork(network)` or `bindProcessToNetwork(null)`, I can't influence other apps on the device. I can only influence my own app.
On a Pixel 3a, all other apps remain having internet. On a Huawei P8 Lite, all other apps remain offline, no matter what I do with `bindProcessToNetwork`

Comment: What happens on the Huawei P8 Lite if you re-connect programmatically to an online Wifi network (using WifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true) ?