# Force application to use WiFi with no connection

Tags: android, android-wifi

We are working on unit which phone connects to it via WiFi and transfers data from it.
The problem is in some phone there is fallback when no internet connection to use mobile data.
If the user disables mobile data connection the application work fine.
How we can force the phone to use WiFi connection when connected to specific SSID and not try to use mobile data?

Comment: As far as I am aware after some trying, you can only force *your app* to use a specific connection. But you can't control what the Android OS will decide for other apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59660494/connect-to-an-offline-wi-fi-and-keep-using-mobile-data-for-all-other-apps-too